# How to get email alert when the windows server 2003 shuts down?

Tags: windows-server-2003

Hi,

one of my servers which is Windows server 2003 has became very old and it is shutting down once in a while. Our admin has been recieving alerts into his pager when it shuts down. That's not a problem. But, we want schedule an email alert into our outlooks also when the server shuts down. How can we do that?

Comment: What make/model is the server?

Answer (score 5):

The administrator probably has a monitoring service/software package that is triggering the pager notification.  Ask them to add an e-mail notification that goes to your e-mail address that is checked by Outlook, or a mailing list that is distributed to the appropriate people.

Comment: +1 someone is monitoring the server to send out the pages, that someone or something could be anything, most likely a service or an application - reconfigure it to also send e-mails. This is not built-in.

Answer (score 1):

If his pager is receiving notifications by using an email address like 1234567890@att.com, etc, you can ask him to simply add another email address (maybe to a shared folder or a list) by adding a comma and the next email address so both of them get notifications.